# How do I get a reference to a ListView?

Tags: java, android, reference

Sorry for being vague, but I'm being instructed to get a reference to the ListView.  How do I do this, or rather, what is this really instructing me to do?  I'm writing in Java for Android.

So far, I've created a ListView on my main activity and the goal is to populate it via an array.

Comment: this gives no information about what your doing or what you need. Need to post the code.

Comment: @Raghunandan Please see the edit I did on my original post.

Comment: still need to post the code. Not enough info. Is it ListActivity or Activity?

Comment: @Raghunandan I haven't written it yet, but someone else posted an answer below.  I'm going to check it out and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

activity

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListview);
```

fragment

```
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewByid(R.id.myListview);
```

Comment: I'm not using fragments.  Does the activity one suffice on its own?

Comment: Just try it or search for findviewbyid.  Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You need the XML part first:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

then you need the Java code:

```
public void onCreate(...)
{
    super.onCreate(...);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list view in your xml like this

```
 <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

then take the reference in your java code

```
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```